# Servlet related basic program

Tags: html

```
//VoterServlet.java
package com.nt.servlet;

    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.io.*;

public class VoterServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public  void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException{
          PrintWriter pw=null;
          String name=null,tage=null;
          int age=0;
          //get PrintWriter 
          pw=res.getWriter();
          //set response content type
          res.setContentType("text/html");

          //get request parameter values(form data)
          name=req.getParameter("name");
          tage=req.getParameter("age");
          age=Integer.parseInt(age);

          //write request processing logic
          if(age>=18){
              pw.println("<h1 style='color:green'>"+name+"You are ELIGIBLE to vote</h1>");
          }
          else{
              pw.println("<h1 style='color:red'>"+name+"You are not ELIGIBLE to vote</h1>");
          }
            //add hyperlink
            pw.println("<a href='input.html'><img src='guns-49a.jpg'></a>");
          //close stream
          pw.close();
    }//doPost(-,-)
}//class
```

Error: incompatible types:int cannot be converted to string **age=Integer.parseInt(age);**

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code

Please correct it

```
 tage=req.getParameter("age");
 age=Integer.parseInt(tage);//use 'tage' instead 'age'
```

Here, you want to get age from 'tage' variable to 'age' variable as a integer value from string.